# Why is body onload not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I'm encountering a problem where my body onload="constructor()" is not being run. It works fine for me in firefox but I don't understand why it's not working for me in chrome. Here's the code I'm working with, I made a separate file and deleted everything to the bare minium to try figure out what was going wrong:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Personality Font</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="p1.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[


        function constructor(which)
        {
            console.log("IN CONSTRUCTOR"); //In Constructor
            var text = document.createElement('p');
            text.appendChild(document.createTextNode("BLAH"));
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(text);

        }

    //]]>
    </script>
</head>

<body onload = "constructor();">
    <h1>Personal Fonts: Find the Typeface that Matches Your Personality</h1>
    <form>

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @barit Where is the parameter which in call?

Comment: @sємsєм It's not used anyways.

Comment: @sємsєм I'm not passing anything in right now with the way the code is written but thanks to Quentin down below I realized my problem was calling my function constructor.

Comment: @barit I did not voted down the question at all! In contrast, I voted it up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chrome has a built-in function with the name `constructor`. Call the function something else.

Comment: Didn't know that before! They could at least make chrome spit out a warning and not let it silently fail.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much! This worked perfectly, I had no idea about that.